# Sumar Datos de una Tabla con DataTable Según una Condición

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo una tabla de 11 columnas, y necesito totalizar las ultimas 4, el problema esta en que si en la Columna 3 existe un valor B04 debe es restar ese valor y no Sumarlo, estoy usando footerCallback que me suma las columnas deseadas

```
 "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api();
            nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
            var j = 6;
            console.log("api", api);
            console.log("nb_cols", nb_cols);
            console.log("j", j);


            while(j < nb_cols){
                var pageTotal = api.column( j, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                return Number(a) + Number(b);
            }, 0 );
                console.log("pageTotal", pageTotal);

      // Update footer
      $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
                j++;
            } 
        },
```

Comment: Veo innecesario ocupar DataTable para hacer de algo tan sencillo un problema muy grande todo porque en la librería es engorroso hacerlo, además de nada te va a servir hacerlo si lo logras si es que el DataTable se carga por ajax

Comment: si es sencillo por que no lo explicas de como se podria hacer